# Collections in POJOs

Tags: java, database, jpa, jdbc, dao

I was generating POJOs from my database using different tools and noticed that some would generate collections as fields, with getters and setters, for one to many relationships and others didn't.

Let's say I have an Order and Product table. Each order can have one or many products.

```
Collection<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(product1);
list.add(product2);
```

Method 1:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setDate(...);
orderDao.add(order);
orderDao.addProductBatch(list)
```

Method 2:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setDate(...);
order.setProductCollection(list);
orderDao.add(order);
```

and in the add method, include an addProductBatch call.

which method is prefered? Also for some one to many relationships adding multiple objects in a single transaction never occurs - in which case you wouldn't need some of these collections - is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the DAO...

In the method 2, you build your order and its products in the business model, then pass the complete and consistent order (order + list of products) to be saved by the DAO. The transaction implementation is internal to the DAO.

In the method 1, you call twice the DAO, first with the order (without product), then again with the list of products related to the order. It means, either that the DAO is stateful and you have some method to execute the transaction when you are done setting it up, or that there is 2 transactions. If you are in the case of this last option, consistency of the DB can be wrong (having an order without any products).

Method 2 is certainly better since it allows stateless DAO, and a clean transaction management.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer variant of the first method. We avoid to use direct data transfer between entities and DAO services in form of collections, but  prefer creation such methods as add, get, remove directly in entity (I know it's some against the rules) - all first needed methods for entity life encapsulates  in entity.